# Mysql query with BETWEEN return only two dates

Tags: mysql

I have following query:

```
SELECT `fecha`, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', `idItem`, `nombreItem`, `cantidad`, `diferencia`) ORDER BY `idItem`) schedule
  FROM inventarioStat
  WHERE `fecha` BETWEEN '1390950000' AND '1391126400'
 GROUP BY fecha ASC
```

The query on itself its fine, Im keep getting selected only two dates, the one Im asking for. How can I get the range beetwen those two, both included. Thanks!

Comment: `between` includes the values you provide. Can you expand what your problem is?

Comment: its not duplicate, the same quety but difrent problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try converting timestamp to date this

```
 SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`fecha`) as fetc , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', `idItem`, `nombreItem`, `cantidad`, `diferencia`) ORDER BY `idItem`) schedule
 FROM inventarioStat
 WHERE `fetc` BETWEEN 'your_first_datetime' AND 'your_second_datetime'
 GROUP BY fetc ASC
```

datetime will be like that : `'2007-11-30 10:30:19'`

Comment: Your right, i did convert the time, but now I have the same result ( only those two dates returns) but in difrent format:)

Comment: then its only two entries which match :), can you post a sample data or a fiddle ??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT `fecha`, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', `idItem`, `nombreItem`, 
`cantidad`, `diferencia`) ORDER BY `idItem`) schedule 
FROM inventarioStat
      WHERE `fecha` >= '1390950000' AND 
`fecha`<= '1391126400'  GROUP BY fecha ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it still return only two dates thou. Is it posible becasue its timestamp?